# x86 virtual address length

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

When reading

> Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals

and Some relevant tutorials about protected mode.
I came across with this question.
According to the manual and the blog 
http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fh-zwickau.de%2Fdoc%2Fprmo%2Fpmtutor%2Ftext%2Fr_phys7.htm  (translated by google)

The virtual address should be 16 + 32 bits,am I right?
So, what is the address with provided when programming using some low level assembly languages? Or, simply put it, what is the address we saw when we are debugging?
It's 32bits I assume.
Is the address in programming or debugging, linear address?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

In usermode on modern x86 systems like windows/*nix, the virtual addresses are either 64-bit (though some bits are currently unused) or 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual addresses on x86 machines are always 32bit, usually with userspace on addresses 0 - 0x7FFFFFFF and kernel addresses 0x8000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF (there are exceptions how the address space is split, of course). The page you posted link to speaks about 16-bit real mode, where addresses are 16-bit but in fact there can be addressed only 1MB of memory, because also the segmentation was used (additional register).

I am not sure why you speak about 16 + 32 bits - maybe you mixed the virtual addressing and segmentation. There are still 16-bit segmentation registers, however, segmentation is deprecated an on most operating systems it is not used. See the Intel manuals you mentioned for details how this works.

Size of virtual addresses has nothing to do with low-level assembly, there you still usually write 32-bit apps (as long as you are not writing your own OS which requires some real-mode code to boot on x86).